# laravel reading object file

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-firestore

![my collection is like][1]

```
foreach ($collection['documents'] as $user) {
    $age = array("name"=>$user['data1'],"gender"=>$user['data3'],"martial"=>$user['data4'],"education"=>$user['data5'],"home"=>$user['data6'],
            "phone"=>$user['data14'],"date"=>$user['data15'],"record"=>$user['data71'],"status"=>$user['data75'],"totalpoint"=>$user['data73'],"monitorypoint"=>$user['data74']);
    $data[]=$age;               
}
```

Error :

> Cannot use object of type MrShan0\PHPFirestore\FirestoreDocument as array

Edit
when i try like this
foreach ($collection['documents'] as $user) {

```
        dd($user->fields);
 
        }
```

Cannot access private property MrShan0\PHPFirestore\FirestoreDocument::$fields
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IvqS.png

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look on [How to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember to provide details on what you want to achieve, what's the issue you're facing and what have you done so far, _is not only about code_. Also, I strongly recommend you to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so the community will have a better insight and it will be easier for people to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating Collections and Documents as arrays instead of objects (as in JSON), thus accessing them in the wrong way. For instance, take a look on the [Firestore Data Model](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/data-model):

> For example, you could have a users collection to contain your various users, each represented by a document:
>
> ```json
> users
>  |___alovelace
>  |    |___first : "Ada"
>  |    |___last : "Lovelace"
>  |    |___born : 1815
>  |___aturing
>       |___first : "Alan"
>       |___last : "Turing"
>       |___born : 1912
> ```

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data), if you want (for example) to access multiple documents within your collection:

```php
$citiesRef = $db->collection('samples/php/cities');
$documents = $citiesRef->documents();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
  // blabla
}
```

Then, you can access fields within a document ([DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.20.1/firestore/documentsnapshot)) as an array:

```php
// One specific field wallet->cryptoCurrency->bitcoin
$bitcoinWalletValue = $snapshot['wallet']['cryptoCurrency']['bitcoin'];
```

See more on [collection()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.20.1/firestore/collectionreference), [documents()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.20.1/firestore/collectionreference?method=documents), [document()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.20.1/firestore/collectionreference?method=document), [data()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.20.1/firestore/documentsnapshot?method=data).

---

#### IMPORTANT

Please note that this **is not an exact implementation of what you should do** as I don't have enough context/information on your database structure. This is just to provide you some guidance.

Comment: foreach ($collection as $user) {
       
            dd($user->fields);    
            }ErrorException
Attempt to read property "fields" on array               so how can i get fields

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you are using to get $collection and the contents of it?